# Sending json to logstash over tcp, keeping connection open, never show up

Tags: java, tcp, logstash

The code below runs in a thread, takes messages off of a queue, and sends them to logstash. I've a unit test that proves that the json (which is the content of the messages) makes it into the socket and gets to the other end.

However, when I point it at actual logstash, nothing ever turns up. I can 'nc' the same content and it shows up. Of course, nc will close the connection at the end of sending the one message. There's a bit of complexity here to reconnect if we ever lose the connection.

The logstash config is pretty simple:

```
input {
 tcp {
     port => 9191
     codec => json
     }
}
output {
    stdout {
       codec => rubydebug
    }
}


         while (true) {
                byte[] message = messages.take();
                executor.getWithRetry(() -> {
                    try {
                        if (socket == null) {
                            socket = new Socket(sinkAddress, port);
                        }
                        socket.getOutputStream().write(message);
                        return null;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        socket.close();
                        socket = null;
                        throw e;
                    }
                }).join();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are sending a newline character at the end of the message. I found that sending "\n" works fine even from a windows box to logstash running on linux.